# how to change the onhashchange value click on browserback button in wordpress ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to fetch the wordpress ajax posts with browswerback button, means when user click on the browser backbutton then post which was previously loaded by click on the title of post will show, i want to show the previous post using browser backbutton, for this i have used this code, it is working fine when user click on the post but it is not working with browser back button, i am stuck with this problem. 
can anyone tell me the solution of this problem.

```
    success: function(response) {
    jQuery("#loading-animation").addClass('loadingstyle');
    jQuery("#loading-animation").text(function(){
    if(location.hash){
    // We got a hash value! Lets take off the hash and smoke it.
    var newhash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);
    // uncomment the above code to see if it works.
    }else{
    alert("No hash available.");
    // no hash value
    }
    $(".ajaxclick").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    });

    // $(window).on('hashchange', function() {

    window.onhashchange = function(){

    // hash changed. Do something cool.
    if(location.hash){

    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    //    console.log(response);
    jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);

    }else{
     // load home page
    // jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);
    alert("No more content to show");
    }
    }       
    });

    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `e.preventDefault();` which causes to stop further events (clicks).

So remove that `e.preventDefault();` from following code

```
$(".ajaxclick").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: i have removed but still it is not working. it simply loads the posts but does not show the previous post with browser button

Comment: window.onhashchange = function(){
        
         // hash changed. Do something cool.
         if(location.hash){
          
           var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
         //   console.log(response);
         // jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);
           
         }else{
           // load home page
          // jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);
           alert("No more content to show");
         }
       }

Comment: this function is not working, in this part only else part is working, when i press the backbutton it display the alert message only

Comment: Hi Ravider your problem is when we click on the backbutton we need display post action is it? currently it is showing previous page is it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace `onchange` function with following code?

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
     if(location.hash){
          var hash = $('.ajaxclick').attr('href');
          jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response);

     }else{
         alert("No more content to show");
     }
}
```

Comment: hi Ravidra can u try this one

Comment: I have used this code for hashchange,it displays the alert when i use backbutton and forward button, but i am stuck that how to change the ajax post content with use of backbutton.because it shows the hashvalue but dont know how to bind hash value with the ajax post conent.
        success: function(response) {
 jQuery("#loading-animation").addClass('loadingstyle');
 jQuery("#loading-animation").html(response,$(function () {
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
 var hash = window.location.hash;
 alert(hash);
        });
        })
        );
        return false;
 }